# Ids param in Google Knowledge Graph API

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I couldn't find a use-case or example of `ids` param in Google Knowledge Graph API. And every time I try putting any id in that field I get an error : `"Request contains an invalid argument."`. I have tried putting all possible arguments there like freebase id, wikiId but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know how to use that argument and it what scenarios it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From its documentation:

To specify multiple IDs in the HTTP request, repeat the parameter in the URL as in ...?ids=A&ids=B

Where A or B is `/m/0c3ss` from an id like this one: `kg:/m/0c3ss`